# Why is this Perl command failing on the Windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, perl

I am trying to replicate the Perl command from [this answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/876354/how-can-i-create-a-csv-file-from-a-directory-listing-with-multiple-columns-based) in a Windows command line environment. I believe I have downloaded [Perl for Windows](https://www.activestate.com/products/activeperl/) and installed it correctly, so the error seems to be one of [syntax](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

The original command in a Linux shell is:

```
ls | perl -pe 's/(.)(.*)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d+).jpg/\u$1$2,$3-$4-$5,$6,$&/' . filename.csv
```

I believe the Windows version should be:

```
dir > perl -pe 's/(.)(.*)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d+).jpg/\u$1$2,$3-$4-$5,$6,$&/' >> filename.csv
```

However, this is the error I'm getting:

```
Invalid switch - "(.)(.*)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d+).jpg".
'/'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

**What is the correct syntax for running this Perl command in Windows?**

Comment: Try what you have with the linux command but change single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: The `.` you have in the linux one might apply to the windows one too, so keep that. (assuming your linux line is fine)

Comment: And basic troubleshooting is try something simple so `s/a/b/` rather than `s/............/........../`  And eventually you might figure out what it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer is **NOT** correct. If you do that you'll still get errors when running in cmd

```bat
C:\Users>dir | perl -pe 's/(.)(.*)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d+).jpg/\u$1$2,$3-$4-$5,$6,$&/'
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
'/'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The reason is due to **multiple issues** in the command

- [Single quote `'` is **not** a quoting symbol in cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24173825/995714)
- [Comma `,`, semicolon `;` and equals `=` are also delimiters](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) beside space and and tab like other shells

Even `/` sometimes separates command arguments like `dir/b/c/d`  or `yourcommand/param` but luckily it doesn't apply in this case. So `'s/(.)(.*)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d+).jpg/\u$1$2,$3-$4-$5,$6,$&/'` will be passed as **multiple parameters** if there are any word separator in it, which is `,` in this case, and the command will be equivalent to

```bat
perl  -pe  's/(.)(.*)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d+).jpg/\u$1$2   $3-$4-$5   $6   $   & /'
```

and your proposed command `dir > perl -pe 's/(.)(.*)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d+).jpg/\u$1$2,$3-$4-$5,$6,$&/' >> filename.csv` will be parsed as

```bat
>>filename.csv >perl dir -pe 's/(.)(.*)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d+).jpg/\u$1$2  $3-$4-$5  $6  $ & /'
```

since `>file` redirection can appear at any places. That causes the `Invalid switch - "(.)(.*)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d+).jpg"` you saw above, because that's not a valid switch to `dir`

That's also the reason why there's an error from perl (not cmd) `Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1` apart from the lines from cmd because in the first parameter begins with `'` but there's no closing `'`. It's easy to check how it's split into parameters:

```bat
E:\>type testparam.bat
@echo off
:loop
if "%1"=="" goto :exit
echo "%1"
shift
goto :loop
:exit

E:\>testparam -pe 's/(.)(.*)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d+).jpg/\u$1$2,$3-$4-$5,$6,$&/'
"-pe"
"'s/(.)(.*)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d+).jpg/\u$1$2"
"$3-$4-$5"
"$6"
"$"
'/'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Now look at the output and notice the funny things happen: because of the ampersand, `&/'` will end the previous command and execute a command named `/'` which doesn't exist and outputs an error like above

---

The best solution is to use **PowerShell**, where you can run the command with just a slight change because [single quote is also used for quoting in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5967407/995714)

```powershell
ls |% { $_.Name } | perl -pe 's/(.)(.*)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d+).jpg/\u$1$2,$3-$4-$5,$6,$&/'
```

`ls` along with `dir` and `gci` in PowerShell alias to `Get-ChildItem`. And you need `|%` ([which is an alias of `ForEach-Object`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39898824/995714)) to print the object names. An alternative in PowerShell is

```powershell
cmd /c dir | perl -pe 's/(.)(.*)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d+).jpg/\u$1$2,$3-$4-$5,$6,$&/'
```

I've left out the redirection for clarity. The output will be printed to stdout. If you want to redirect it to file just append `>filename.csv` or `>>filename.csv` depending on whether you want to overwrite or append

Running the command in cmd would be far more troublesome (and new code should use PowerShell anyway, as it has been the default options for a long time)

```powershell
dir | perl -pe 's/(.)(.*)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d+).jpg/\u$1$2^,$3-$4-$5^,$6^,$^&^/'
```

In this case changing `'` to `"` also works, but it'll quickly break in many other situations

```powershell
dir | perl -pe "s/(.)(.*)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d+).jpg/\u$1$2,$3-$4-$5,$6,$&/"
```

---

Note that even in Linux your command is also **wrong**

```bash
ls | perl -pe 's/(.)(.*)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d+).jpg/\u$1$2,$3-$4-$5,$6,$&/' . filename.csv
```

You need `>filename.csv` instead of `. filename.csv`

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses `|` as the pipe character too. Copy the command directly, but replace `ls` with `dir` and `filename` with expenses.csv

*Added as answer because I don't have the reputation to comment*

Comment: In conjunction with some of the comments, this was the command that actually ended up working: `dir | perl -pe "s/(.)(.*)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d+).jpg/\u$1$2,$3-$4-$5,$6,$&/" >> filename.csv`

Comment: your solution won't work because single quotes are not special in cmd