# Can I get this Perl command on Windows to not generate dates with apostrophes in LibreOffice?

Tags: csv, libreoffice, openoffice, perl

Based on the help I got on [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1404656/103956), I have this Perl command that I run in Windows 10 PowerShell:

```
ls |% { $_.Name } | perl -pe 's/(.)(.*)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d+).jpg/\u$1$2,$3-$4-$5,$6,$&/' > filename.csv
```

The purpose is to list all the files in a directory with pre-formatted filenames and create a CSV file where those file names are divided up into separate columns. Each filename is a scan of a receipt, and the filename contains information like the date and cost and type of expense.

A filename looks like this:

```
expense_name_20200212_300.jpg
```

After running the Perl command above, and I open the file in Notepad, LibreOffice, or any other editor, the filename above will be rendered as:

```
expense_name,2020-02-12,300,expense_name_20200212_300.jpg
```

I do not know what part of the Perl Command places dashes in the date, because I don't know anything about Perl, but that's what it does.

For the most part, the command above works fine. It creates a CSV file as hoped.

However, one problem is that when I open the CSV file in LibreOffice, the dates will not accept any date formatting. This is because in the cell of each date, the date has an apostrophe appended to it. I think this is because LibreOffice interprets the date field as text, and marks it as such, even though it is all numbers. The format in the original file name is YYYYMMDD, but is rendered in the CSV as YYYY-MM-DD.

I have learned how to remove that apostrophe following instructions on [this web page](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=49046). But it would be ideal to not have all those extra search and replace steps.

**Is there a way to get the Perl command above to create a CSV file where LibreOffice will recognize the date field as numbers and not append an apostrophe?**

Comment: You said “the original file name is YYYYMMDD, but is rendered in the CSV as YYYY-MM-DD.”, I don't see any apostrophe here. Please, edit your question and add full example with input string, output string you get and output string you expect. Why do you add hyphens in the date?

Comment: @Toto, thanks for responding. I added a point in the question regarding date formatting as you requested. To be clear: I do not do any manual editing of the date, the Perl command takes YYYYMMDD format from the file name, and outputs it as YYYY-MM-DD in the CSV file. I do not know anything about Perl, so I can't offer any explanations about how or why, I can only confirm it does by running the command and checking.

Answer (score 1):

Opening a CSV file in LibreOffice should bring up the text import screen. Select the date column and change it to `Date (YMD)` type.

[image: Text Import - Fields]

Then press OK to open as a Calc spreadsheet.